# Easiest way to execute JavaScript when listitem updates?

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, dashboard-designer-2013

What is the easiest way, in SharePoint 2013, to execute JavaScript when listitem updates?

For example,

- Can SharePoint Designer 2013 do this?
- Is there any way which does not involve WSPs, Apps or Sandbox solutions?

Comment: It would be more helpful to understand what you are trying to accomplish a little better. Then we might be able to suggest a way to do it that you might not have considered yet.

Comment: I would need to execute an event when a listitem updates. We have traditionally done this in a WSP but now we need to survive without server-side code running in SharePoint. I see one possibility being a high-trust provider-hosted app - which would work - but the functionality is so simple that simple CSOM or calling some SP2013 REST services would solve the problem. Calling REST should work from Designer 2013 but we need to prepare and operate on the data sent/received so some javascript would be required in order for this to work.

Comment: (answering to your question about what we are trying to accomplish - we would need to change the current list item's folder (preserving list item ID) using current user credentials. Both WSP, CSOM and REST provide this functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, workflows do not have the ability to execute javascript. You'd need to account for that on a custom edit page on saving the item, then hand off any components the workflow is supposed to do at that point.

Comment: So apparently we could either tweak REST calls in Designer (http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/using-the-call-http-web-service-rest-calls-in-sharepoint-online-using-spd/), write an App or do something creative as David Lozzi suggests?

Comment: Yep, there aren't any means natively to execute javascript in a workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get creative:

- Workflow updates a list item
- JavaScript on masterpage pings the list, looking for this updated list item
- If found, JS does its thing

Bad side is that you have JS querying every time the page loads, but it's an async call, so shouldn't hurt too much.

Comment: Nice idea. Or a remote scheduled task or a worker role pinging the latest changes, and doing the changes via web services? Here we might need to use other than current user credentials though.. Or perhaps even installing a remote REST service which a Designer workflow will call on listitem update (http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/using-the-call-http-web-service-rest-calls-in-sharepoint-online-using-spd/) and that service would use CSOM to operate on the current item - could that work?